# Can't delete Draft Post

Tags: plugins, posts

I am new to wordpress and was happily blogging along when I ran into a weird issue. I tried uploading a gif into the draft and the editor crashed. I refreshed the browser and then found that I couldn't access all posts or the drafts of posts from my post dashboard.

Where you would expect to see the table of posts I see this error, and the drafts table doesn't populate at all despite showing one draft:[image]

You'll notice the posts I created after the error no problem, but the posts from before the error aren't shown.

I tried following the guides I could online to fix the issue, and I figured out that when I disable all my plugins I can see it in the drafts:
[image]

However, when I try to 'trash' the draft, it gives me a critical error.

Please let me know if there is any additional troubleshooting information that you need to help, otherwise thank you for your time and attention.